# How to sort list depending on substring?

Tags: python, django

I have this list sorted:

```
>>> L = ['actor_1', 'actor_3', 'actor_130', 'actor_55', 'actor_5']
>>> L.sort()
>>> L
['actor_1', 'actor_130', 'actor_3', 'actor_5', 'actor_55']
```

Is there a clean way to make the list sortable by the number after underline to have it like the following?:

```
['actor_1', 'actor_3', 'actor_5', 'actor_55', 'actor_130']
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify `key` function which generate comparison key:

```
>>> L = ['actor_1', 'actor_3', 'actor_130', 'actor_55', 'actor_5']
>>> def sort_key(s):
...     s, n = s.split('_')
...     return s, int(n)
...
>>> L.sort(key=sort_key)
>>> L
['actor_1', 'actor_3', 'actor_5', 'actor_55', 'actor_130']
```

Comment: If you want to sort ascending first on the RH digits then on the LH string you should swap s and int(n) to be `return int(n), s` Otherwise -- great answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can separate the number into another list and sort both together.

```
>>> L = ['actor_1', 'actor_3', 'actor_130', 'actor_55', 'actor_5']
>>> n = [int(x.split('_')[1]) for x in L]
>>> n
[1, 3, 130, 55, 5]
>>> L = [x for (y, x) in sorted(zip(n, L))]
>>> L
['actor_1', 'actor_3', 'actor_5', 'actor_55', 'actor_130']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex and a key lambda:

```
>>> L.sort(key=lambda s: int(re.search(r'_(\d+)',s).group(1)))
>>> L
['actor_1', 'actor_3', 'actor_5', 'actor_55', 'actor_130']
```

Since Python's sort is [stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability), if you want the list sorted first by the string to the left of the underscore then by the number to the right just sort in place twice:

```
>>> L = ['actor_1', 'actor_3', 'actor_130', 'actor_55', 'voice_5', 'actor_5']
>>> L.sort()
>>> L.sort(key=lambda s: int(re.search(r'_(\d+)',s).group(1)))
>>> L
['actor_1', 'actor_3', 'actor_5', 'voice_5', 'actor_55', 'actor_130']
```

Or you can do the same thing by returning a tuple in your key function to sort first on the digit, then on the LH string:

```
>>> L.sort(key=lambda s: (int(re.search(r'_(\d+)',s).group(1)),s))
>>> L
['actor_1', 'actor_3', 'actor_5', 'voice_5', 'actor_55', 'actor_130']
```

Or:

```
>>> L.sort(key=lambda s: (int(s.split('_')[1]), s))
```

It is *often* [faster](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Sort_Stability_and_Complex_Sorts) to do two sorts rather than one complex sort.